# Laravel Multiple Edit/Upload File

Tags: laravel, file, controller, upload, switch-statement

I want to make my code more efficient in my Controller. This code is about to update file in the database and then delete the file were chosen, rather than use if-condition i will use switch statement and then call the updateFile function for each case of file name. But i have problem on my switch statement, it supposed to run for each case but doesn't.

```
private function updateFile($strFileName, $oldFileName){
        if($request->file($strFileName)){
            if($request->$oldFIleName){
                Storage::delete($request->$oldFIleName);
            }
            $validatedData[$strFileName] = $request->file($strFileName)->store('post-files');
        }
    }


 public function update(Request $request, Task $task)
    {   
        //storing files request
        $rules = [
            'file_jamlak' => 'mimes:pdf,png,jpg|file|max:4096',
            'file_kontrak' => 'mimes:pdf,png,jpg|file|max:4096',
            'file_jamuk' => 'mimes:pdf,png,jpg|file|max:4096']

        //validate rules in to new variable
        $validatedData = $request->validate($rules);
        
        //the switch
        $file_name = $request->file();
         switch($file_name){
            case 'file_jamlak' : $this->updateFile('file_jamlak', 'oldJamlak');
         }
 
       //condition
       //jamlak
        if($request->file('file_jamlak')){
            if($request->oldJamlak){
                Storage::delete($request->oldJamlak);
                // return $request->oldJamlak;
            }
            $validatedData['file_jamlak'] = $request->file('file_jamlak')->store('post-files');
            $validatedData['jamlak'] = 1;
        }

        //kontrak
        if($request->file('file_kontrak')){
            if($request->oldKontrak){
                Storage::delete($request->oldKontrak);
            }
            $validatedData['file_kontrak'] = $request->file('file_kontrak')->store('post-files');
            $validatedData['kontrak'] = 1;
        }

       //add user id
        $validatedData['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;

        //update eloquent
        Task::where('id', $task->id)
        ->update($validatedData);
        
        //dd($file_name);
        return redirect('/admin/tasks')->with('success', 'New post has been updated!');

}
```

i think i made mistake on the $file_name, that it supposed to store file name but doesn't work. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've file name in your case which you are checking against:

```
// ... 

//the switch
$file_name = $request->file();
switch($file_name){
    // make sure this name matches the name of the file you are submitting
    // from the form on front end to be able to fall into this case
    case 'file_jamlak' : $this->updateFile('file_jamlak', 'oldJamlak');
// ...
```

Comment: i checked with dd($file_name) after i input some pdf file, and it shows me this 
array:1 [▼
  "file_jamlak" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1332 ▶}
]

do you have any idea how to seperate that "file_jamlak" index and make it to be value on switch?

Comment: if your use case is to that the input from form remain consistent; i.e it will always be file1.jpe, file2.jpg etc; you should put this in to your cases; otherwise pattern matching: switch with pattern matching